# How can I make VS Code treat unused variables as problems?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I saw a colleague in WebStorm highlighting unused variables. How can I enable this in VS Code?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot pretty much shows what you need: [ESLint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) + [TypeScript ESLint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin) + [the `no-unused-vars` lint rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.md).

The minimal `.eslintrc.json` config file for this might look similar to this:

```json
{
    "root": true,
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
    },
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["warn"],
    }
}
```

Note that TypeScript itself supports emitting warnings / errors for unused local variables via [its `noUnusedLocals` tsconfig setting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUnusedLocals).

Comment: Does your solution solve the problem of exports never being imported? I'm not sure

Comment: @Edshav what are you talking about? I didn't get that that was a problem from the question post. If it is, then the question post should say so explicitly. All their question post currently says is "_I saw a colleague in webShtom highlighting of unused exports, how to enable this in VS Code?_"

Comment: For reference: the question isn't actually about unused _exports_, it's about unused _variables_. The fact that a variable is unused because it was meant to be exported and is not used locally is irrelevant.